# llvm - get users of an instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-gcc, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to get the users of alloca instruction (to basically get the users of a variable). I am using the following code to do so:

```
virtual bool runOnModule(Module &M)
{
        for(Module::iterator F= M.begin(), E = M.end(); F != E; ++F) // iterating over functions in a module
        {
            for (Function::iterator FI = F->begin(), E = F->end(); FI != E; ++FI)    // iterating over BB in a function
            {
                for (BasicBlock::iterator I = FI->begin(), E = FI->end(); I != E; ++I) // iterating over instructions in the BB
                {
                    Value* v = cast<Value>(I);
                    v->user_begin ();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

However, it's giving me the error:

```
error: ‘class llvm::Value’ has no member named ‘user_begin’
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and suggest a possible solution to what I'm trying to do here (get users of a variable)?

Comment: Could it be that you use an old version of LLVM that does not have this API?

Comment: As @AlexDenisov wrote. What version of LLVM do you use?

Comment: LLVM 3.4 as far as I remember

Comment: That's really outdated version. The most recent one is 7.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly use user_begin without casting Instruction to Value.
Just like:

```
I->user_begin()
```